# Cannot force version increment on non-versioned entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking, hibernate-6.x

I have a versioned entity that I optimistically lock whenever I read it from the database using `@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)`.

I was originally using spring boot 2.7.11 and upgraded to 3.2.0. Everything was working fine before and `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` was thrown whenever a conflict occurs, however when I upgraded to spring boot 3.2.0 and hibernate version was upgraded to 6.3.1, I get `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: cannot force version increment on non-versioned entity`

here is the entity definition:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Case {

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Merchant merchant;

    @Column(name = "case_creation_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date caseCreationDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Agent agent;

    @Column(length = 2000, nullable = true)
    private String note;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "case_justification")
    private Collection<Justification> caseResolutionJustifications;

    // constructors

    // setters and getters

}
```

and here is the read query:

```
@Repository
public interface CasesRepository extends JpaRepository<Case, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
    Optional<Case> findById(Long caseId);
}
```

I thought it may be a mapping issue, I dropped the table and let hibernate create the table again, still have the same issue.

Comment: OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT causes version incrementation of all entities that are fetched, including Merchant and Agent. Do they have a version field?

Comment: @AntonKozub Yes, they are both versioned.

Comment: They shouldn't have to be - JPA says nothing about the lock cascading. Locking (my take on it) is only meant to be applied to the root entity of a graph. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14579 as it seems a bug to me

Comment: @Chris I thought it shouldn't have too, I had been using hibernate 4.x.x and that wasn't an issue back then. However, when I upgraded to hibernate 6.x I recently found that all entities that are fetched in a query need to be versioned. The problem was that even the join table for OneToMany, ManyToMany and ManyToOne relations need to be versioned too.